# Open Graph on mobile (iOS)

Tags: ios, api, android-activity, facebook-opengraph

I would like to realize an iPhone app with Facebook OpenGraph to push user activities directly in Facebook (for this part, it's OK). BUT, I would like to show friends activities for the same **verb**. In dev Facebook documentation, I don't find API to get friends activities...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

GET /me/{namespace}:{action-type}

GET /me/{namespace}:{action-type}/{object-type}

Don't forget to ask for the permissions firends_actions:namespace

Namespace = namespace of your app

Answer (score 0):

**Find friends with the app (this gives you a nice tidy list)**

Option 1. Use Fql.query so you can apply filters and get back only what you need...

```
Fql.query POST
SELECT uid, name, pic from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user=1", @"query
```

option 2. Use opengraph and get back a mother list of friends with their ID any fields you want to read (installed status shown)

```
GET me/friends&fields=installed
```

**Then use the Friends list to download their {action-type} executions**

Option1. Enumerate through your friends activity with this and then bare it all:

```
GET /friend_id/{namespace}:{action-type}
```

option 2. Force the user to browse the list of friends with the app...
They choose the friend and then ->

```
GET /friend_id/{namespace}:{action-type}
```

They get a list of that users last 25 actions.
It's how instagram works when you browse.

The thing we all want is to just have a feed with the last 25-50 actions by friends. Just like the activity plugin. At this point it seems like there is no way to get it. I spent hours searching and everyone ends up saying you need to do it manually on your own server. I wouldn't be surprised if this activity function is added to the graph sdk eventually. It's a reasonable request.